# Sending POST with groovy to payment gateway

Tags: grails, post, groovy

I have already found similar topics but my code doesn't work.
I need to connect a webshop with payment gateway.
Data must be sent with POST. The problem is that when I want to open the payment form, I get only the info web page about the payment gateway.

Here are parts of my code:

cart.gsp

```
<jq:jquery>
$("#buy").click(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'${createLink(action: 'fetchPaymentForm')}',
            success:function(data,textStatus) {},
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {}
        });
        e.preventDefault()
})
</jq:jquery>
```

This part of code runs when I click on button with id "buy".

shoppingCartController.groovy

1. version

   ```
   def fetchPaymentForm(){
     def restClient = new RESTClient("https://test.payment.com/redirect/")
            def resp = restClient.post(
                    body: [target: "_top", mode: "form", 
       store_id:"${storeID}", orderNumber: "${orderNumber}", 
       language: "${language}", currency: "${currency}", 
       amount: "${amountAll}", cart: "${cart}", Hash:"${hash}",     require_complete: "true"],
               requestContentType: URLENC
       )
    }
   ```
2. version

   ```
      def fetchPaymentForm(){
         render(template: "/layouts/paymentForm", model: [orderNumber:     orderNumber, amount: amountAll, currency: currency, language: language,     storeID: storeID, cart: cart, hash: hash])
        }
   ```

_paymentForm.gsp

```
<form method="POST" action="https://test.payment.com/redirect/"     name="form" id="form">
    <input id="target" name="target" value="_top" type="hidden">
    <input id="mode"  name="mode" value="form" type="hidden">
    <input id="store_id"  name="store_id" value="${storeID}"       type="hidden">
    <input id="order_number"  name="order_number" value="${orderNumber}"     type="hidden">
    <input id="language"  name="language" value="${language}"     type="hidden">
    <input id="currency"  name="currency" value="${currency}"      type="hidden">
    <input id="amount" name="amount" value="${amount}" type="hidden">
    <input id="cart" name="cart" value="${cart}" type="hidden">
    <input id="Hash"  name="Hash" value="${hash}" type="hidden">
    <input id="require_complete"  name="require_complete" value="false"     type="hidden">
</form>
```

I would be very thankfull if someone could give me an advice or hint what to try.

EDIT:
Here is an example for redirect for C# which is shown in pdf file for payment implementation.

```
<input id="target" ClientIDMode="Static" name="target" value="_top"        hidden="true"/>
<input id="mode" ClientIDMode="Static" name="mode" value="<%=mode %>" hidden="true"/>
<input id="store_id" ClientIDMode="Static" name="store_id" value="    <%=store_id %>" hidden="true"/>
<input id="require_complete" ClientIDMode="Static"     name="require_complete" value="<%=require_complete %>" hidden="true"/>
 <input id="order_number" ClientIDMode="Static" name="order_number"     value="<%=order_number %>" hidden="true"/>
<input id="amount" ClientIDMode="Static" name="amount" value="<%=amount     %>" hidden="true"/>
<input id="hash" ClientIDMode="Static" name="hash" value="<%=hash %>"     hidden="true"/>
<input id="currency" ClientIDMode="Static" name="currency" value="     <%=currency %>" hidden="true"/>
<input id="cart" ClientIDMode="Static" name="cart" value="<%=cart %>"     hidden="true"/>
<input id="payment_number" ClientIDMode="Static" name="payment_number" value="<%=payment_number %>" hidden="true"/>
<input id="language" ClientIDMode="Static" name="language" value="<%=language %>" hidden="true"/>
<asp:button id="Button2" Text="testcps"
PostBackUrl="https://test.payment.com/redirect/" runat="Server"     ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Obviously I'm missing something but I don't know what. 
Thanks for tips in advance.

Comment: What is the `fetchPaymentForm()` method for?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question. fetchPaymentForm() is an action in shoppingCartController. I use it for gathering data which I sent to payment gateway.

Comment: What's throwing me off is that your two versions are **completely** different, so I can't quite tell what you're trying to do. By different, I mean they don't even attempt to accomplish the same thing. I *think* you're trying to submit data to a remote service via an HTTP POST. And I'm assuming that service requires authentication and SSL encryption. Firstly, is the service accessed via a REST endpoint? It doesn't look like it. Second, did you already take care of authentication? Basically, it seems you're getting redirected because you're accessing the service incorrectly.

Comment: Payment provider created for me SSL certificate and that is ok. The service is not accessed via a REST endpoint.

Comment: Ok, then consider using Groovy's `HttpClient` instead.